# Type argument K is not within bounds of type-variable K

Tags: java

I am getting errors in the test class for wrong implementation of K and comparable. It says "type argument K is not within bounds of Type-variable K:

Binary Search Tree Class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<K  extends Comparable<K>> implements Tree<K> {
    public Node(K data, Node left, Node right) {
        .....

}
```

Test Class:

```
private <K> int get_height(BinarySearchTree<K>.Node p) {
    .......
}
```

I assumed I needed to change it to...

```
private <K> int get_height(BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>>.Node p) {
        .......
    }
```

However this leads to errors such as "unexpected bound"

Comment: Try `private <K extends Comparable<K>> int get_height(BinarySearchTree<K>.Node p)`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Done.

Answer (score 1):

`BinarySearchTree` expects a `K` which `extends Comparable<K>`. You can specify this when declaring type parameter of your generic method `get_height`:

```
private <K extends Comparable<K>> int get_height(BinarySearchTree<K>.Node p) {...}
```